# Extracting data from db with time based SQL injections

Tags: sql-injection

**SCENARIO:**

a vulnerable login form. I say vulnerable because if I enter `+select(sleep(0))+` the server response normally. If I enter `+select(sleep(5))+` the server wait for a period of time greater than 5" and then responds with `"connection failed"`. **Can be this considered a proof of SQL injection?**

**Could I leverage this  difference in the responses to conditionally extract data from the db?**

The high-level idea is:

```
if user(1,1) is 'a' then sleep(0) else sleep(1)
```

Comment: sqlmap has tools for this. Are you aware of sqlmap?

Answer (score 1):

Does the connection time out at approx. 5 seconds? If so, then it is very likely vulnerable. You could verify by then modifying it to 3 seconds, and seeing if it responds in approx. 3 seconds.

If the connection takes longer than 5 seconds, it is possible this is a very strange SQL query, or there is a WAF or some other functionality detecting blacklisted keywords. They may be throwing you a red herring! It's happened to me before in this exact situation during a manual engagement.

Answer (score 1):

**Can be this considered a proof of SQL injection?**

This definitely is proof of SQL injection. Specifically, this is Blind SQLi where you are using functions such as *sleep()* to confirm the presence of information in the database.

**Could I leverage this difference in the responses to conditionally extract data from the db?**

As schroeder put it, it is worth using automatic tooling for blind SQLi.

For more information on Time-Based Blind SQL Injection Attacks, also refer to https://www.sqlinjection.net/time-based/